# How to copy workspace to a folder and run maven clean install using a batch file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, automation

Can anyone help me please? 
I am trying to create a script which will copy my project directory to a different location, then after the copy finishes, it will run  maven clean install on it.
The reason for such a request is because my project takes alomost 10 minutes to build which blocks me from keep doing work whilst it is being package into WAR files.

What i have is

```
 xcopy /Y /S "C:\Users\userName\workspace\Java-API" "C:\Users\userName\Downloads\dummyTest"
echo Finished copying stuff

cd .\trent\
echo We are in trent folder

mvn clean install
echo finished maven clean install

pause
```

Then i go to that directory and run mvn clean install.

Is there a way to automate it so the first script that i run will:
    Copymy working directory (which can take time)
    Wait for it to finish copying over
    Then run maven clean install
    Then move the war files into WildFly deployment folder

Thank you

Comment: What do you _really_ want to do? Why should you always copy your directory? Don't you use git/svn?

Comment: Hi i work on a massive maven project. for me to do a clean install it takes about 9 minutes. What i was trying to do is to automate this, by copying my maven project to a dummy location, then do a clena install there so i dont have to wait almost 10 minutes each time i want to build my war files and deploly on WildFLy.

Comment: Why is a clean install faster if you copy the project first? I don't understand.

Comment: You are right it is not faster, it only let me keep working on my project whilst it does the build on a separate project. Idealy it would get a copy of my code, build the war file from it, followed by moving it to my wildfly deployments folder. So all of this would happen parallel. So i would never stop working on my code. It is very Jenkins like